# IPv4-only Wifi in an IPv6-enabled OpenWRT router

Tags: wireless-networking, ipv6, openwrt

I have a router with OpenWrt and IPv6 connectivity through a tunnel (HE.net). I need two Wifi connections: one with IPv4 and IPv6, and another one with IPv4 only. Is this possible? Maybe I can set up a firewall rule to block IPv6 traffic on the IPv4-only Wifi network, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy enough. For the interface corresponding to your second wireless SSID, disable IPV6 assignment, router advertisement and DHCPv6 service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up doing that, but first I had to actually create the second interface. This is basically what I did: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/guest-wlan-webinterface